# The definition of probability mass function. Does the random variable has to be discrete?

Tags: probability, random-variables, definition

In my text, the definition of probability mass function is here.

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space, and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a discrete random variable, i.e., $X(\Omega)$ is finite or countable. Then, define the probability of $X=x$ by $P(X=x):=P(\{\omega\in \Omega \mid X(\omega)=x\})$ for $x\in \mathbb R$. And define the probability mass function $f_X:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by $f_X(x)=P(X=x)$ for each $x\in \mathbb R$.

---

I wonder why this definition supposes that $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a discrete random variable. Isn't it good if $X$ is simply a random variable ?

I couldn't find the reason why $X$ has to be a discrete.

Comment: For discrete random variables, you have the probability mass function (pmf), and for continuous random variables, you have the probability density function (pdf),

Comment: The point is that PMF is defined for discrete random variables because *continuous* random variables have probability zero of being any specific value. Like the answer below mentioned, for a continuous (which is not discrete) random variable, the nonzero probabilities can only occur over a range. Using the given definition you have, if X is continuous (so not discrete), then $f_X(x) = P(X = x)$ is going to give you exactly $0$ for all points in $R$, which is not exactly useful to work with..

Comment: Sorry for the unrelated question, but may I know what textbook you are using in this particular case? I'm browsing for books related to Probability Theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $P(X=x)$ refers to the probability that $X$ is exactly $x$. For a continuous r.v., we consider the probability of $X$ within a range. The probability of $X$ *equal to* a particular value is always **0**.

Technically speaking, a continuous r.v. is usually presented in this way:

$P(a\leq X\leq b)=\int_{a}^{b} f_X(x)dx$

Therefore, $P(X=c)=\int_c^c f_X(x)dx=0$.

In terms of verbal interpretation, you may consider a continuous uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, i.e. $X\sim U[0,1]$. Since there are infinitely many values within the domain, $P(X)=\dfrac{1}{\infty}=0$.

Therefore, the definition of probability has to be revised if it is to be extended to continuous r.v.